# How to make the icons work on Panel and Window Manager?

Tags: icons, openbox

How do you get Window Manager and Panel to show up icons in Linux? I am not able to get the icons working for Zathura and Termite applications. I use **OpenBox** with **Tint2** as the Panel.

`termite.desktop` and `zathura.desktop` have `Icon="name"` entry present. And those images are present in `/usr/share/pixmaps` and `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/apps/16x16 - 48x48` folders. `zathura.desktop` has a generic Icon called as utilities-terminal which is the same for most of the standard desktop utilities. I do see the Icon when I navigate to /usr/share/applications folder for both Termite and Zathura. It however doesn't show up in WM and Panel.

I read that there is a function that can be called by application that sets these icons. It can check for icons in user's theme or else default to a standard icon like Firefox does. Is there a way to control this and force an icon for the application?

It looks pretty much like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications themselves set the Icon and it need not be based on the GTK Theme. Firefox for example hardcodes the Icon Image. Some applications allow it to be supplied in their rc files.

For zathura you can change ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc

`set window-icon /full/path/to/image`

For Termite you can change ~/.config/termite/config

`[options]
...
icon_name = terminal
...`

There is also this beautiful tool called [xseticon](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xseticon/)